# CupertinoSliverNavigationBar largeTitle multiline

Tags: dart, flutter

I am creating a Flutter application which uses the Cupertino widgets. Now I am using the `CupertinoSliverNavigationBar`, but I did like the title to be multiline. 
Currently I have written the following:

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CupertinoPageScaffold(child: CustomScrollView(slivers: <Widget>[
      CupertinoSliverNavigationBar(largeTitle: Text(
          "Why doesn't this text wrap? I want it to be multiline...")),
      SliverFillRemaining(child: Container())
]));
}
```

I tried several ways, like putting the `Text` in a `Flexbile` but this is not working. Any idea in how I can achieve the desired effect?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried setting the `softWrap` property to `true` for the `Text` widget?

Answer (score 0):

The height of the largeTitle is limited and I have found anything to make it bigger, so the solution that I propose require to make the text smaller.

```
largeTitle: RichText(
                text: TextSpan(children: [
                  TextSpan(
                      text: "Why doesn't this text wrap?",
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 20)),
                  TextSpan(text: "\n"),
                  TextSpan(
                      text: "I want it to be multiline...",
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.orange, fontSize: 20))
                ]),
              ),
```

I think you should avoid using multiline largeTitle but in case you really want it you can try this.

Comment: When the large title is collapsed to the middle, is there anyway to keep the middle text centered on both lines, while maintaining the left justification of the large title?